# DAX porblem with a sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate a simple sum of sales for different products but i have a visualization problem.

I have 2 different tables:
"Master data" where i can find all the informations about a porduct (product ID, description etc)
"total sales" where i can find for each product_ID the total sales amount

These tables are connected by a relationship based on the "product_ID".

I have created a table with product_ID (from "Master data") and total sales (from "total sales") but it returns the same amount of sales for every product ID (the sum of sales of all products)

Exemple:
product_ID_1  100€
product_ID_2  100€
product_ID_3  200€

I visualize the incorrect values like this:

product_ID_1  400€
product_ID_2  400€
product_ID_3  400€

Thanks in advance!!!

Ersilia

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely impossible!

If you put 'Master Data'[Product ID] next to [Sum Total Sales] in one table visual, then 'Master Data'[Product ID] will filter [Sum Total Sales].

If you see the Total of [Sum Total Sales] in every row, then YOU ARE NOT FILTERING, because you clearly don't have a relationship between 'Master Data' and 'Total Sales'. Check that in the Model view: The line is either missing, or dotted (inactive).

But with the given sample data from above you should have a one-to-one relationship between the Product ID's, although in general this will be a one-to-many relationship, since every product is probably sold more than once.

I'd recommend using more general sample data to check this out and not to use the same names for tables and their columns and esp. not 'Total' everywhere, so that you don't end up with such confusing expressions like "Total of [Sum Total Sales]". This is asking for trouble.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your comment. 

I've just checked and I  have an active one-to-many relationship between "master data" and "sales" tables based on the product ID. I cannot understand how it is possible that the filter on the product _ID is not working. 
I can't find a solution :(

Comment: I shouldn't have answered in the first place, because without you sharing some sample data like [recommended by Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this is all unfruitful guesswork.

Comment: But please don't back down. This is the point where you can learn something.